# I am trying to automate a postman collection, in GitLab, using a google service account. How do I authenticate the service account and send a request?

Tags: gitlab, postman, gcloud, google-cloud-pubsub, service-accounts

Backgroud:
I have a Google pub/sub topic that I can publish to using Postman. I would like to put this postman collection into GitLab and use a gcloud service account to run the collection without any manual intervention (e.g having to generate a bearer token and copying into the Postman collection).

Problem:
My Dev created and gave me a .JSON key file (screenshot below) for a service account that has the permissions to publish messages to my topic.

[image]

I have hit a road block where I don't know how to pass the bearer token from bash into my collection. This is what my .yaml file, in GitLab, looks like so far:

```
stages:
    - test

postman_tests:
    stage: test
    image: 
        name: postman/newman_alpine33
        entrypoint: [""]
    script:
        - newman --version
        - npm config set unsafe-perm true
        - GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=~/path-to-my-serviceaccount-key.json gcloud auth application-default print-access-token
        - newman run name-of-my-collection.json -e name-of-my-postman-environment.json
```

the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=~/path-to-my-serviceaccount-key.json gcloud auth application-default print-access-token` prints out a token but I don't know how to pass it to the collection. Am I doing this right?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with postman|newman but `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is an environment variable that's (to my knowledge) only used by Google SDKs and it won't be something that Postman expects. The bearer token that you generate must somehow be provided to the Postman API calls via a header... The curl equivalent is `curl .... --header "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" ` and you'll need something similar

Comment: BTW since you're installing (!?) `gcloud` into the container, you may wish to consider [`oauth2l`](https://github.com/google/oauth2l) instead. This is a Google utility that you can use to grab a [`header`](https://github.com/google/oauth2l#header) from service account credentials more directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the following code:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=KEY_FILE
```

After that you can print your identity token using:

```
gcloud auth print-identity-token
```

After that pass this as auth header:

```
curl -H "Authorization: bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)" <your usual curl params>
```

Hope this helps.

1. [gcloud auth activate-service-account](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account#--key-file)

Comment: This is the best answer I found online in authorizing via google service account with an example and all. Thanks for your support!

Comment: You're welcome!